# Redmine served via Apache / Unicorn

Tags: apache-2.2, unicorn

I am currently trying to get an instance of redmine up and running. I have been successful so far, however I am now hitting a road block with the apache / unicorn configuration.

The following conf is included with my httpd.conf for apache.

```
ProxyPass /redmine balancer://redmine
ProxyPassReverse /redmine balancer://redmine

<Proxy balancer://redmine>
     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4000
     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4001
     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4002
     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:4003
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Proxy>
```

The issue is that The pages generate do not have any formatting or assets, and all the links do not include host/redmine prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Redmine that you're serving on a path that isn't the domain root.  As per [the fine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI), you need to add the following line at the bottom of your `config/environment.rb`:

```
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Then restart.

Comment: I forgot about that lol, Thanks so much that solved my problem =)

Comment: It is cleaner to use `config/additional_environment.rb`, as `config/environment.rb` is meant to be managed by Redmine, is under their version control and may change over time. See my other answer: https://serverfault.com/a/850827/175421

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to create `config/additional_environment.rb` with:

```
config.relative_url_root = '/redmine'
```

followed by restarting your Redmine instance.