# Unicorn: Sub-Url Generated Links Broken

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, redmine, unicorn

I am currently trying to stand up an instance of redmine, however currently The generated links in my redmine instance are all broken. I am attempting to serve redmine from a sub-url i.e example.com/redmine

I have searched, but I have not found any information on a prefix option (similar to mongrel)

I currently have the assets and formatting working properly, from my previous question.

[Redmine served via Apache / Unicorn](https://serverfault.com/questions/406075/redmine-served-via-apache-unicorn)

My current setup is apache / unicorn

Thanks in adavanced

**EDIT**

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194

rails --version
Rails 3.2.6

unicorn --version
unicorn v4.3.1

httpd -version
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jun  9 2012 01:42:02
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by adding `ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = "/redmine"`
to `additional_environment.rb` as per 
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI